# Entity Manager Type and Associate Transaction

Tags: jpa, transactions, entitymanager

AFAIK, there are two types of entity manager. 
1. Container managed entity manager
2. Application managed entity manager

1. Container managed entity manager

   - This type of em uses JTA transaction only

Below is my code:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "", type = Transaction)
EntityManager em;


public void persist(T entity) {
em.persist(entity)
}
```

Questions: 
There is exception throw when execute the code : TransactionRequireException
Why there is this kind of exception? There is no TransactionRequireException happen after added @Resource UserTransaction to the method persist(). I wonder UserTransaction is belongs to JTA right.

```
EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
```

Refer to the above code, Why JTA transaction type cannot invokes getTransaction() ?

Can extended JTA Transaction em use outside of EJB?

1. Application managed entity manager

   - Utilize JTA Transaction
   - Utilize JDBC Transaction(Resource Local Transaction)

Please anyone provide example of source code on JDBC Transaction type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JPA persistence unit can either be JTA or RESOURCE_LOCAL.

If you use JTA, then you must use JTA for transaction, either through SessionBeans or by accessing JTA directly.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Runtime#Java_Enterprise_Edition